# Can't init TypeORM project

Tags: npm, typeorm

I'm trying to create a new TypeORM project and have run the following commands, according to the TypeORM documentation:

```
npm install typeorm -g

typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property EntityManager of #<Object> which has only a getter
at Object.<anonymous> (~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typeorm/index.js:120:23)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typeorm/commands/SchemaSyncCommand.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

I get the same error even if I just try to run

```
typeorm
```

Comment: Also have this problem. Looks like it's due to the use of "use strict"

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
"resolutions": { 
    "tslib": "1.11.2"
}
```

to your package json, tslib 1.12 breaks typeorm

Comment: Note: this only works for yarn. `npm-force-resolutions` package can be used to apply it with npm.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround that did it for me was this:

`npm i tslib@1.11.2 --save` and remove the `^` before the version in package.json of my project.

The open issue can be found [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6054)

Comment: --save is not necessary anymore

Comment: Works with the ```^``` as well. No need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's apparently an issue with one of the dependencies used by TypeORM. The dependency tslib 1.12.0 apparently breaks TypeORM. If you've installed TypeORM globally, go to your install folder (default is probably /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typeorm) and edit the package.json file. Change the version of tslib to "1.11.2". Then run `npm update` to update the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was facing the same problem and I've created a file called `ormconfig.json` at the project's root with my credentials.

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "pass",
  "database": "database_name"
}
```

After that the problem is no more.

Before I had tried the user840250's solution. It worked for the original problem but it had created another one: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No connection options were found in any of configurations file`.